# RUBY RAILS - Allow user to write in option that is not in drop down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Still pretty new to ruby.. How would I add a feature to this drop down to allow users to enter an attribute that is not in the drop down list. Right now when I try to add something it says no results matched.

```
        <%= f.select(:attribute_type, @attribute_types, {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control selectpicker', data: {'live-search' => 'true'}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The no results matched message is because you are not adding something to the select, but you are searching in the select list.

If you want users to have the option to fill in whatever they want instead of selecting it drop the select you can just add an input field below the select.